# Searching constant value through all Simulink blocks

Tags: matlab, find, simulink

I have a big Simulink model with a lot of User-Defined MATLAB functions. And I went wrong way - I used some local data in many blocks. For example - water density. I just used `1000` in formulas or some local variables like this: `wat_den = 1000;` in a lot of different functions (`MATLAB function` blocks). 
And now I got the problem - I tried to simulate my model for another liquid (so, another density). Now I understand, that I have to use all this variables in another way - I create table of all constant and route them to functions directly.

And my question - is it possible to find variable or numeric value in all functions? because Ctrl+F can't finds inside of any user-defined functions (it can find only signal's names, port names, etc) and I forced to open every block and check it's content.

Comment: do you have an mdl or slx file?

Comment: You could save your model as .mdl file and use your favorite text editor to search for the value; mdl files are quite legible. (.slx files are binary)

Comment: I agree with Tom, that was what I was about to suggest. But I wouldnt recommend to convert an slx file to an mdl file for such a bug model. I couldn't tell what information get lost.

Comment: You can move the content of all `MATLAB Function` blocks to separate `.m` files in form of function and only call those functions from these blocks. This way you can search in all those text files. I usually do this because it also helps when you use a version control software. You can easily take a diff of those functions instead of the model files.

Comment: @Tom, yes! it works! I can see all blocks, all their parameters. But I'm  unlucky: I need to find all values of `2700` and finding all the times `TiledPaperMargins [1.270000, 1.270000, 1.270000, 1.270000]` :)

Comment: @thewaywewalk I create a copy of project in .mdl. And just find in it blocks which use my values and change them just in .slx

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia say me plz - with type of connection for your .m file use? I tried to use it in ModelExplorer/Callbacks but then I need to restart model if I change it .m. I also tried S-Functions, but it works much more longer then Matlab Function block in simulink!

Comment: See the answer http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102675-how-do-i-specify-the-matlab-code-for-the-function-in-an-embedded-matlab-function-block-from-the-matl which gives you a programmatic way of accessing the code in MATLAB Function block. You can get the code and then programmatically search for your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do this by doing **CTRL + SHIFT + F**

It will open up a gui and you can write in the field: *Find Files containing text: * the name of your variable.

This will search all the instances of that variable throughout your Current Folder (you can even change where to search).

Note: You can change the extension of the file you want to search.

I hope this helps. I am using Matlab r2015b

Comment: It really works! But one more problem: all found values are in .slx. So I can't see where exactly is it inside .slx project. Is it possible to see where is it? (simulink block/subsystem). 
I can right click at found values and click "Open" but it just opens simulink project.

Comment: Hi, 
I did not found a solution to that yet. I will come back here if I find one. 

What I noticed is that when, in the results, it comes up a simulink model SIMULINKMODEL.slx you should look, for the searched string, in an embedded function of your model SIMULINKMODEL.slx.

Please upvote my answer or accept it if you found it useful.

Comment: Yep I see this. But .slx is a binary, so the string number is useless...

Comment: No, I meant: 

you are searching for the string 'thisIsMyString' with ctrl+shift+F. 

Then you get an occurence in SIMULINKMODEL.slx . It means that if you open SIMULINKMODEL.slx there has to be an embedded function with 'thisIsMyString' inside.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Ye ye, I got it. The question was is it possible to find block (or system/subsystem) in simulink that contain this 'myString' variable? But thank you for response!